# Magento 2 How can I validate the email confirmation field with the actual email field?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, email, validation, confirmation

I have added confirm email field in my contact form. Now I want to validate it. How can I validate this email confirmation field with the actual email field?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the ***second reenter email address*** input  your need to add a  `paremeter  equalTo:'#email'`  to `data-validate`, Where  `email` is ***your email address input field's id attribute value***.

> ```
> data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true,equalTo:'#email'}"
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can add another Email field in your contact us form and add validation rules like below:

> data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true, equalTo:'#email'}"

```
<div class="field email required">
    <label class="label" for="confirm_email"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Confirm Email') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input name="confirm_email" id="confirm_email" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('email') ?: $this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true, equalTo:'#email'}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can check other validation rules using the below link:

http://blog.i13websolution.com/magento-2-validation-rules/

Answer (score 0):

The validators list in UI Components it can be found in

```
vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js
```

In your example you can use this:

```
validate-email
```

just add this tou your input tag .

```
data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"
```

So your code can be like here:

```
    <label for="email_address" class="label"><span><?php echo __('Email') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="email" name="email-recheck" id="email-recheck" value="" title="<?php echo __('RE-Enter Email Address') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}">
    </div>
```

Comment: I want to validate the 2 emails are same

Comment: The ID in my code is different from your default email form, so will be validate

Comment: this code will validate the email field. I want to check the email1 value and email-recheck values are same or not. If it is not same then show the error message 'Please enter the same value again.'