# Error message for email and confirm email validation

Tags: validation, form-validation, magento1.9.3

I have 2 fields in form .

```
1.user email 
2.confirm email.
```

If I fill on user email field and moved to confirm email field then enter wrong email i.e; not same as user email, it is showing error "both emails should be same" so in this scenario, it is corect.

**other scenario**

If I fill on user email field and moved to confirm email field then enter same as user email then edit user name to some other name but it is not showing error message

I need error message on this scenario as well

```
    <input 
       name="useremail" 
       id="useremail" 
       title="<?php echo $this->__('User Email') ?>" 
       value="" class="input-text required-entry validate-email"                   type="text" />

    <input 
       type="text" 
       name="confirm_email" 
       id="confirm_email" 
       title="<?php echo $this->__('Confirm Email') ?>" 
       class="input-text required-entry validate-cemail" 
       value="" onpaste="return false;" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use simple jquery you can do something like that

```
function confirmcheck(){
   var email= $('#useremail').val(); 
   var confirmemail= $('#confirm_email').val();    
   if(email==confirmemail){
      $('.alert').html('<span>email and password are same</span>');
   }
}
$('#useremail').on('change',function(){
  confirmcheck();
});
$('#confirm_email').on('change',function(){
  confirmcheck();
});
```

**Update: 1**

```
data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true,equalTo:'#email'}"
```

For Detail You can see [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/199762/78648)

Comment: @Waquar  by default magento not providing? I mean for this class="input-text required-entry validate-email" not possible?

Comment: please see my updated answer

Comment: it is not working..I placed like this <input 
       type="text" 
       name="confirm_email" 
       id="confirm_email" 
       
       class="input-text" 
    data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true,equalTo:'#useremail'}" >

Comment: can you check in your "<form" element data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}' is there or not ?